# How to create a Django image gallery

Tags: python, django, image, gallery, portfolio

I am looking to create a portfolio using Django. I have tried using ImageField but it only allows me to upload and replace 1 photo.

I am new to Python and Django programming. How would I create a model to upload multiple images and show them in a gallery? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use apps like [photologue](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/), [imagekit](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit), etc to simplify some of the tasks.

You may also upload multiple images using [Model Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)

Comment: I have used photologue multiple times. Very easy to setup for a simple photography gallery and also good as a base from which to build a customized solution by subclassing.

Comment: I just took a look at photologue and it could fit what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://web.archive.org/web/20120621233904/http://lightbird.net/dbe/photo.html
That will explain the basics.

If you want to add more then one pic through the admin you can do something like this:

```
class ChoiceInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Image # or what ever your models name is
    extra = 5 # or how ever many you want to add at a time
```

You should also go through the Django tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Thanks, I am looking through the lightbird tut. Should help a ton

Comment: This has been updated for newer versions of Django in the [portfolio app](http://lightbird.net/dbe2/portfolio.html#addimages-and-imageview)

Answer (score 2):

Just put the following code in your gallery template.

```
{% for image in images %}
                {% if forloop.first %}
                    <div class="row ">
                {% endif %}
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-12" >
                    <div class="text-center mt-2">
                        <img src="{{image.image.url}}"height="70%" width="70%" class="img-thumbnail" alt="...">
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
                    </div>
                    <div class=row>
                {% endif %}
                {% if forloop.last %}
                        </div>
                {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [django-galleryfield](https://github.com/dzhuang/django-galleryfield). BTW, I am the author of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial that walks you through [building an image gallery with Django](https://engineertodeveloper.com/how-to-build-a-photo-gallery-with-django-part-1/) using both the admin panel and using formsets if your web app has users who can't access the admin panel.